# Accessing object values within an object

Tags: angularjs

I have a array of objects as shown below

bookingdetails

```
[Object, Object]
0:Object
__v:0
_id:"57fe328ab82311cf37055b8b"
1:Object
__v:0
_id:"57fe328ab82311cf37055b8c"
```

Am trying to display _id using ng-repeat but am getting blank. Code is as below

```
<div ng-repeat="res in bookingdetails">
        id : {{res._id}}
</div>
```

Comment: The value of array you have posted above, Is it logged from same scope as of `ng-repeat` ? Can you post codes of that controller ?

Comment: Show us the code of the controller. Is there any error inside the console ?

Comment: Try using just `res.id`.

Comment: I did not bind it to scope.. silly mistake..